callback queue , call stack and registered event like setTimeout
what happens if any event is register (like setTimeout) but it takes more time (assume 5,6 min ), and currently call stack and callback queue is completed all task and it is empty, so the program is waiting to execute it or js is ended this program??
here is ex.
console.log("Starting..");

setTimeout((a, b) => {
  console.log("2 sec Timer");
}, 5000000);

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("Immediate Timer");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("0 sec Timer");
}, 0);

console.log("Ending..");

is js wait for 5000000 ms or it end the execution?

hi, this question is a bit vague. please provide source code to demonstrate your needs.

2 seconds is 2000, not 5000000. That number is in milliseconds. -- setImmediate is deprecated.

Curiosity... What does console.log("2 sec Timer", a, b) return for a and b?

IIUC, you're asking whether or not the program will stop even before executing the delayed command? If so, you can simply try it yourself and see..

setTimeout is a timer function to postpone an execution.
The provided callback will be executed after that timeout AND as soon as the stack is free. So it is actually called, but waiting to execute.
Unless an error occurs, the script will execute till its end.
Here is an exercise to look at.


// Console functions for this demo
const showTime = () => new Date()
const variableInc = () => {
  variable++
  console.log('variable', variable)
}
// ===

// Here is a basic variable
let variable = 1
console.log('variable', variable) // variable 1

// See the order of execution below.
setTimeout(async() => {
  console.log(`${showTime()} - Starting a big task 500ms after...`)
  variableInc() // variable 4
  const promiseThatTakesTime = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    variableInc() // variable 5
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 60000) // 1 minutes... Like to get some big data from a remote API
  })
  await promiseThatTakesTime
  console.log(`${showTime()} - The 1 minutes task finally finished.`)
  variableInc() // variable 7
  try{
    throw new Error('Whooops... Something when wrong!')
  } catch(error){
    console.log('Got an error:', error.message)
  }
  console.log('END')
}, 500)

console.log(`${showTime()} - Hello! I' here right now at execution launch.`)
variableInc() // variable 2

setTimeout(async() => {
  console.log(`${showTime()} - 1500ms after...`)
  variableInc() // variable 6
}, 1500)

setTimeout(async() => {
  console.log(`${showTime()} - 10ms after...`)
  variableInc() // variable 3
}, 10)



CodePen
If you want to play with timings, read the doc about setTimeout, Promise, await and try...catch.
